# FirebaseException: The operation couldn't be completed. No APNs token specified before fetching FCM Token

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm not sure what else I need to do to get the FCM Token. Perhaps I'm missing a step. Below are the details of my current setup.

This is an Unity iOS build calling GetTokenAsync.

```
Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.GetTokenAsync();
```

However, I'm getting an exception.

```
FirebaseException: The operation couldn’t be completed. No APNS token specified before fetching FCM Token
```

I've generated an APN Key for push notification and uploaded to Firebase, but I'm not sure do I need to included it somehow with Xcode?

I've enabled Background Modes.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple reasons this could be happening. The following instruction steps are included in the [Set up FCM for Unity Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/unity/client).

Try each of the following (if you haven't already):

- Enable Push Notifications in Xcode under **App > Capabilities**
- Add **UserNotifications.framework** in **Linked Frameworks and Libraries**
- Switch **Push Notifications** to **On** in capabilities
- Make sure method swizzling is **enabled**

If this doesn't work then look through the logs before and after the message you are getting above and see if there are earlier messages relating to warnings or failures with FCM or APNS.

Please tell me how it works out for you.

Comment: To make sure method swizzling is enabled do you set "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to "YES" in Info.Plist?

Comment: I think I'm missing "RequestAuthorization", but I'm not sure. Do I still need this with FCM? https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mobile.notifications@1.4/manual/iOS.html

Comment: If "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" is present, set it to Yes as you mention.


As for "RequestAuthorization", you can use [RequestPermissionAsync](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/blob/master/messaging/testapp/Assets/Firebase/Sample/Messaging/UIHandler.cs#L89) as shown in the [Unity Quickstart example for FCM](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/blob/master/messaging/testapp/Assets/Firebase/Sample/Messaging/UIHandler.cs#L89).

Answer (score 0):

use following pod version it will work

```
pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '10.6.0'
```

add following properties in info.plist

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
    <false/>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use last version of firebase_message and firebase_core.

```
firebase_core: ^2.17.0
firebase_messaging: ^14.6.9
```

this will work fine.